# Export My Google Map to KMZ File for Google Earth

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kmz

I have developed and google map with v3 in javascript as well as vb.net for some server side code to attach the map with database.here is link of my map

http://202.125.144.34:80/Map/Cotton.aspx

Here is My complete code for making this map which is working well

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Cotton</title>

  <script runat=server>

      Dim mgps As New Text.StringBuilder

      Public ReadOnly Property GPS() As String
          Get
              Return mgps.ToString

          End Get
      End Property



  </script>  

  <%  Dim con As New OleDbConnection
      con = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=sml; User ID=sml; Password=sml; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
      con.Open()
      Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from GPS_MAP", con)


      Dim ds As New DataSet
      Dim I As Long

      Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
      da.Fill(ds, "GPS_MAP")
      mgps.AppendLine("[")

      For I = 0 To ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows.Count - 1
          'AppendLine("new google.maps.LatLng(" & ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE") & "),")
          'station.AppendLine(ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE"))
          Dim station As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("STA_NAME")
          Dim party As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("PARTY_NAME")
          Dim address As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("ADDRESS")
          Dim namerep As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("NAME_REP")
          Dim avg0809 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("AVG_08_09")
          Dim avg0910 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("AVG_09_10")
          Dim avg1011 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("AVG_10_11")
          Dim avg1112 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("AVG_11_12")
          Dim brk0809 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("BRK_08_09")
          Dim brk0910 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("BRK_09_10")
          Dim brk1011 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("BRK_10_11")
          Dim brk1112 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("BRK_11_12")
          Dim bales0809 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("BALES_08_09")
          Dim NETWT0809 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("NETWT_08_09")
          Dim bales0910 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("BALES_09_10")
          Dim NETWT0910 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("NETWT_09_10")
          Dim bales1011 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("BALES_10_11")
          Dim NETWT1011 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("NETWT_10_11")
          Dim bales1112 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("BALES_11_12")
          Dim NETWT1112 As String = ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("NETWT_11_12")
          mgps.AppendLine("{GPS:new google.maps.LatLng(" & ds.Tables("GPS_MAP").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE") & "), TITLE:'" & station & "',BALES0809:'" & bales0809 & "',NETWT0809:'" & NETWT0809 & "',BALES0910:'" & bales0910 & "',NETWT0910:'" & NETWT0910 & "',BALES1011:'" & bales1011 & "',NETWT1011:'" & NETWT1011 & "',BALES1112:'" & bales1112 & "',NETWT1112:'" & NETWT1112 & "',PARTYNAME:'" & party & "',ADDRESS:'" & address & "',NAMEREP:'" & namerep & "',AVG0809:'" & avg0809 & "',AVG0910:'" & avg0910 & "',AVG1011:'" & avg1011 & "',AVG1112:'" & avg1112 & "',BRK0809:'" & brk0809 & "',BRK0910:'" & brk0910 & "',BRK1011:'" & brk1011 & "',BRK1112:'" & brk1112 & "'},")
      Next I
      mgps.AppendLine("];")

      con.Close()
      %>  


    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script src="http://acme.com/javascript/Clusterer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
 var map;

 var markers = new Array();

 function initialize() {
    var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(31.2330555556,72.3330555556);


var GPS = <%=GPS %>
     var myOptions = {
      zoom: 9,
      scaleControl:true,
      pancontrol: true,
      streetViewControl: true,
      center: map_center,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    //var clusterer = new Clusterer( map );

    for(i=0; i<GPS.length; i++)
    {

        //  var image = 'ico/no.png';


          markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker(
          { 
           position: GPS[i].GPS,
           map: map,
           draggable:true,

          Info:'<table style="border:1px solid #000000;font-family: Arial; font-size:10px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>'+
                '<td colspan="6" style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;">'+
                    '<span style="font-family: Arial"><b>'+ GPS[i].PARTYNAME + '</b></span></td></tr><tr>'+
                '<td colspan="6" style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;">'+
                    '<span style="font-family: Arial">'+ GPS[i].ADDRESS +'</span></td></tr><tr>'+
                '<td colspan="6" style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;">'+
                    '<span style="font-family: Arial">'+ GPS[i].NAMEREP + '</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;"></td>'+
                '<td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;"><span style="font-family: Arial">Bales</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;">'+
                    '<span style="font-family: Arial">Net Weight</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;">'+
                    '<span style="font-family: Arial">Average rate per Maund</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;">'+
                    '<span style="font-family: Arial">Broker</span></td></tr><tr><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;">'+
                    '<span style="font-family: Arial">2011-2012</span></td><td rowspan="4" style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;"></td>'+
                '<td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; text-align:right;"><span style="font-family: Arial">' + GPS[i].BALES1112 + '</span></td>'+
                '<td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; text-align:right;">'  + GPS[i].NETWT1112 + '</td><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; text-align:right;">'+ GPS[i].AVG1112 + '</td>'+
                '<td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; ">'+ GPS[i].BRK1112 + '</td></tr><tr><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;">'+
                                  '<span style="font-family: Arial">2010-2011</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; text-align:right;">'+
                    '<span style="font-family: Arial">'+ GPS[i].BALES1011 + '</span></td> <td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; text-align:right;">'+ GPS[i].NETWT1011 + '</td>'+
                '<td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; text-align:right;">'+ GPS[i].AVG1011 + '</td><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;">' + GPS[i].BRK1011 + '</td></tr><tr>'+
                '<td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;"><span style="font-family: Arial">2009-2010</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; text-align:right;">'+
                    '<span style="font-family: Arial">'+ GPS[i].BALES0910 + '</span></td>'+
                '<td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; text-align:right;">' + GPS[i].NETWT0910 + '</td><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; text-align:right;">'+ GPS[i].AVG0910 + '</td>'+
                '<td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; ">'+ GPS[i].BRK0910 + '</td></tr><tr><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;">'+
                    '<span style="font-family: Arial">2008-2009</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; text-align:right;">'+
                    '<span style="font-family: Arial">'+ GPS[i].BALES0809 + '</span></td><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; text-align:right;">'+ GPS[i].NETWT0809 + '</td>'+
                '<td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0; text-align:right;">'+ GPS[i].AVG0809 +'</td><td style="border:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:0;">'+ GPS[i].BRK0809 + '</td></tr></table>',
           title:GPS[i].TITLE

           });                      

            google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(this.Info);
            infowindow.open(map,this);
            });             

         }    
      }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" style="text-align: center">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%; text-align: center;">
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any Possibilty to export this map to make a kmz file to be open in Google earth.If nay one know then please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out your map link and it looks good; I like the InfoWindow tables you have tied to the marker clicks.

But I think you have to tell a little bit more about exactly what you want to achieve with the KMZ:

- Do you simply want to *recreate* your existing map as kmz for display in Google Earth?
- Or do you want to literally create a dynamic export implementation that reads from your database using the latest data?

Comment: Yes Of course I want to create a dynamic export implementation that reads from my database using latest data.and thanks for the infowindow.

Comment: Then I think you basically have everything you need. You will be able to recreate each marker as a KML _Placemark_ that contains a _Point_. You will then be able to attach a marker or a custom img to the Point to make it look like your existing map. From there, you will be able to pretty much take you the existing table markup you are currently displaying in the InfoWindow and transfer that over as well. Info about KML support in Google Maps is here: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport

Comment: But Sir there is Not any Complete Method to convert or export my existing google map to kmz or kml file.Please tell me steps or some sample code to do this

Comment: Well, that was my original question and you said you wanted to create a dynamic export implementation. If you just want to recreate your existing Map in KML, you can use your existing code as a starting point and write the code to export the structure, but substitute Placemarks with Points for the markers.

Comment: Sir Sorry to Say But there is not any sample code or example exist in your answer to export map to kmz or kml file.Kindly show some sample code or any link which expalins the actual question

Comment: I suggest starting with the [Placemarks](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#placemarks) sample section of the overall [KML Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut).